# What do you think the Stack Overflow proposal would have looked like?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, area-51

If we somehow did some weird time warp so that Area51 existed but not Stack Overflow, what do you think the Stack Overflow proposal would have looked like?

What would have been some example on and off topic questions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Would stackoverflow.com survive area51?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54069/would-stackoverflow-com-survive-area51)

Answer (score 3):

How can I parse HTML with regex?

Answer (score 1):

What's your favorite illegal substance to absorb while coding?

Comment: Clearly off-topic, but would probably end up locked after a long close-war.

Comment: I would have to move to a country where caffeine was illegal to answer this question

Answer (score 0):

Why is [PHP] so [slow]?

Answer (score 0):

What's the best book to learn `[programming-language]`?