# Area 51 - Where's Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, area-51

Where is Stack Overflow on Area 51?

Usually, when you head to search and type something like EL&U (I wanted to check the stats), it pops up.  But when I search Stack Overflow, nothing comes up.  Why is this?

Comment: Short version: it predates Area 51, just like a few other sites (e.g. SuperUser). Long version: there's probably a duplicate ...

Comment: Stack Overflow never went through Area 51.

Comment: @Glorfindel dupe?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54069/would-stackoverflow-com-survive-area-51

Comment: Since the question ask for commun stats, information on all SE site can be found at https://data.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since I can't find a duplicate: Area 51 was created after the trilogy ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/) and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)) split. Also, this site, Meta Stack Exchange existed back then as Meta Stack Overflow.

The first site to launch from Area 51 was [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) (it's at the bottom of [this page with launched proposals](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched&page=2)). Other Q&A sites without a matching Area 51 proposal (for various reasons) are:

- [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)
- [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/)
- [CS50](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/)
- [Русский язык (Russian Language in Russian)](https://rus.stackexchange.com/)
- [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com)

Comment: There is a fuller list/duplicate here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284184/377214